# Can calibrating a probabilistic classifier make it worse?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

With the release of scikit-learn 0.16 and the new `CalibratedClassifierCV` I thought I'd try it out on a personal project.  When I did it actually made the cross-validated log-loss worse for the logistic regression, random forest, and gradient boosted trees classifiers that I was using.  Does this make sense?  Do I just need to tune the `CalibratedClassifierCV` better, or is it possible that using it makes my classifiers worse?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html

Comment: Can you check 0.16.1? There was an instability in IsotonicRegression in 0.16.0

Comment: Still slightly worse with 0.16.1.  Could it be because I'm using less data to fit the original model?  Is its weird (perhaps a sign of a bug) that it is even worse (terrible actually) when I use the 'profit' option and fit the model and the calibrator on the same data?

Comment: No, fitting on the same data should definitely make it worse. To convince yourself that the calibration works, you could fit on the training set and calibrate on the test set, which would help (obviously these are not valid results as you leak information from the test set).

Comment: And yes, it could be slightly worse because you use less training data for the actual model.

Comment: I answered to a similar question where it was tested on a generated dataset (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285551/why-does-calibratedclassifiercv-underperform-a-direct-classifer/32027398#32027398). Apparently the performance can be lower when the number of folds for the calibration is low (which is the default).